# How to import complex XML Types in Oracle SQL using XMLTABLE

Tags: xml, oracle

I have the following XML Files completely imported in the table called ARCHIVDATA into one single cell called CLOB_CONTENT:

```
<AuditLog>
  <AuditLogEntry>
     <Header>1
     </Header>
     <Content>2
     </Content>
  </AuditLogEntry>
  <AuditLogEntry>
     <Header>3
     </Header>
  </AuditLogEntry>
  <AuditLogEntry>
     <Header>4
     </Header>
     <Content>5
     </Content>
     <Content>6
     </Content>
  </AuditLogEntry>
</AuditLog>
```

What I want as a result is the following table (table with two rows):
**Header | Content**

1      | 2
3      | NULL
4      | 5
4      | 6

How can I do that?

I already tried the following:

```
SELECT x3.header, x4.content
FROM (select xmltype(xml.CLOB_CONTENT) xmldata from ARCHIVDATA) x1,
     xmltable('/AuditLog/AuditLogEntry'
         passing x1.xmldata
         columns
             header XmlType path 'header',
             content XmlType path 'content'
         )x2,
         xmltable('/header'
         passing x2.header
         columns
             header varchar2(4000) path '.'
         )x3,
         xmltable('/content'
         passing x2.content
         columns
             content varchar2(4000) path '.'
         )x4
;/
```

What do I have to change to get the desired result table?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this task with next query. But I am sure that more easier way exists.

```
SELECT headers.header,
  contents.content
FROM
  (SELECT extracted."Header" AS header
  FROM ARCHIVDATA a,
    xmltable('/AuditLog/AuditLogEntry' passing xmltype(a.CLOB_CONTENT) columns "Header" VARCHAR2(6) PATH '/AuditLogEntry/Header') extracted
  ) headers
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT sel.Header,
    sel2.content
  FROM
    (SELECT extracted."Header" AS header,
      extracted."Content"      AS content
    FROM ARCHIVDATA a,
      xmltable('/AuditLog/AuditLogEntry' passing xmltype(a.CLOB_CONTENT) columns "Header" VARCHAR2(6) PATH '/AuditLogEntry/Header', "Content" xmltype path '/AuditLogEntry') extracted
    ) sel,
    xmltable('/AuditLogEntry/Content' passing sel.content columns content VARCHAR2(6) path '/Content') sel2
  ) contents
ON headers.header = contents.header;
```